# How to get the result of SMS on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I used the "MFMessageComposeViewController" to send SMS and used the method -"messageComposeViewController: didFinishWithResult:" to get the result .However,the result is ambiguous.Because I always get "MessageComposeResultSent" as long as I click the "send" button,even the number doesn't exit.

So is there some API(public or private) can be used to get the result of SMS? Thank you for your future help.

Comment: What information do you want to get out of the result?

Comment: I want to know if the msg is send successfully .

Comment: I believe that there is no way. Apple doesn't allow for that kind of access to users information.

Comment: It's not even the "user's" information.  You would need to have access to whether or not the phone on the other end successfully received the message.

Comment: To put it simply,now, I want to resolve the following issue.If I send a msg to number "123"(or any number doesn't exit),I should get the feedback－Send failed.